# How to restore grub after cloning hard disk for a dual boot laptop

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I had a dual boot (Windows/Linux Mint) laptop with a 500GB SSD, and replaced the SSD with a 1TB SSD using the procedure described below. When I reboot, it boots directly into Windows, without grub menu. Why did this happen, and how can I restore the grub menu?

This is what I did:

1. Boot the laptop from a live bootstick (running Linux Mint)
2. Use dd to copy the whole 500GB SSD to a network drive
3. Shut down the laptop and replace the SSD by a 1GB SSD.
4. Boot again with a live bootstick and use dd to copy the file on the network drive back to the SSD.
5. Reboot without live bootstick

I know that this leaves half of my new SSD unused; I was hoping to fix that later.

dd worked correctly, or at least I can mount all partitions including live partitions from a live bootstick.

Here are some hardware details:

Laptop: Dell XPS 15 (9550)

Old SSD: PM951 NVMe SAMSUNG 512GB

New SSD: Kingston Technology KC2500 M.2 1000 GB PCI Express 3.0 3D TLC NVMe

Pastebin link, from Boot-Repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DkMGvNXdYq/

In case it matters: Windows fast boot was disabled when I cloned the disk.

Comment: I do not know LVM, but know you will have  issues trying to expand it with NTFS partitions surrounding it. Try turning off UEFI Secure Boot. And maybe a full reinstall of grub using Boot-Repair's advanced mode. You may need to manually mount LVM first for Boot-Repair to work correctly. You also have an old BIOS boot grub in gpt's protective MBR. That should never be used & should not have been installed. But as long as you always boot in UEFI mode, it will not otherwise cause issues.

Comment: @oldfred I managed to boot using grub again (see below).  Still need to expand the partitions,  will see how that goes,  thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: LVM, well in this case cryptsetup/LUKS are a PITA. If you want to encrypt things, VeraCrypt is far less of a mess.

Comment: FYI: Resizing the partitions using gparted worked with only a minor hickup: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656572/gparted-refuses-to-move-my-linux-partition-why/656581#656581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,  the problem was that the Bios decided that it would be a good idea, given the new SSD, to select the Windows bootloader instead of Grub,  without telling me.

I learned that UEFI has a separate FAT32 partition which can contain multiple bootloaders,  which are executable files with `.efi` extension,  and that the BIOS of my Dell XPS15 laptop has well-hidden settings to choose which bootloader will be used.  The right one for me was ubuntu/shimx64.efi (for secure boots) or grubx64.efi (non-secure),  and not EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi (Windows).

`efibootmgr` (a very useful hint from @Artem S. Tashkinov) could also have fixed this problem.

Comment: So I guess you have to enter BIOS and find out the setting that allows you to choose the bootloader. Mind telling me which BIOS section is this setting?

Comment: It is in General > Boot sequence,  in the "boot list option" frame. It appears that "boot options" means "bootloaders" i.e. EFI files,  a point that was not obvious to me

Answer (score 1):

Boot using any LiveCD and then refer to these tutorials:

- https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/how-to-use-linux-efibootmgr-examples
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Efibootmgr

This can be done from Windows as well using EasyUEFI and other similar tools.

Comment: Haven't thought about that because `dd` never fails, but yeah UEFI is a huge cesspool like any Intel "security" features (TSX, etc). I do also know that some operating system (not sure if Windows does, but it whould) do use a drive's last bytes to store data for booting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues booting to GRUB on my dual-boot laptop after resetting the UEFI values to their defaults. I was able to recreate the missing UEFI boot option using `efibootmgr` like this. Please note that I leave Secure Boot enabled so I use shimx64.efi as my loader.

```
# Create a new boot option
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1 -L Fedora -l \\EFI\\fedora\\shimx64.efi

# Check the result - compare with the Windows entry
efibootmgr -v
```