# Gparted refuses to move my Linux partition; why?

Tags: partition, gparted

Recently,  I installed a larger SSD in my laptop (dual boot Windows - Mint) and copied my existing data to it.  After fixing boot issues (see [How to restore grub after cloning hard disk for a dual boot laptop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656180/how-to-restore-grub-after-cloning-hard-disk-for-a-dual-boot-laptop?noredirect=1#comment1234710_656180)),  I am now trying to re-arrange the partitions to make use of the extra space.  In particular,  I am trying to use `gparted` to allocate some of the space to my Windows partition.

The current partition layout (using GPT) is shown below.  The main Windows partition is partition 3. There is a lot of free space (953321473 sectors, about 488GB) between partition 6 (main Linux partition) and 7 (Microsoft basic data).  Partitions 7, 8 and 9 were already moved to the end of the disk using `gparted`,  which worked fine,  and the laptop boots both Windows and Mint.

To be able to allocate more space to the Windows partition,  I need to move partitions 4, 5 and 6 closer to the end of the disk. `gparted` does not allow me to move partition 6 (option is greyed out),  and doesn't give any error message explaining the problem either.

Partition 6 is my Linux Mint partition and it is internally using LVM. The virtual partition for /home is encrypted.  Could that somehow be the problem?

Any other suggestions on how to move this partition?

I have tried `gparted` versions 1.0.0 and 1.3.0 (latest) from a live boot stick;  neither worked.

```
johan@graograman:~\> sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for johan: 
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 282E2059-1738-4156-802F-50E4A4E71652

Device              Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    1026047   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    1026048    1288191    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1288192  205020339 203732148  97.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4  205021184  206086143   1064960   520M Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme0n1p5  206088192  214087679   7999488   3.8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p6  214087680  969730047 755642368 360.3G Linux filesystem

/dev/nvme0n1p7 1923051520 1923973119    921600   450M Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p8 1923973120 1951283199  27310080    13G Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme0n1p9 1951283200 1953523711   2240512   1.1G Windows recovery environmen


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-root: 60 GiB, 64424509440 bytes, 125829120 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-home: 300.3 GiB, 322462285824 bytes, 629809152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 3.8 GiB, 4095213568 bytes, 7998464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Additional information: in the `gparted` window,  partition 6 has a little key icon.  What does that mean?  See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Got it:  Partition 6 is an LVM2 PV. Before you can move an LVM2 PV in `gparted`,  you need to deactivate it using *Partition > Deactivate*.